# Create regex for url with numbers after www. and mails with number after @

Tags: c#, html, regex, url

I am no good in regex that is why posting this.I have code to get all the urls and also all the emails from html. But i need the following. I can get all the urls using below:

```
Regex regx = new Regex("http://([\\w+?\\.\\w+])+([a-zA-Z0-9\\~\\!\\@\\#\\$\\%\\^\\&amp;\\*\\(\\)_\\-\\=\\+\\\\\\/\\?\\.\\:\\;\\'\\,]*)?",
                        RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                        MatchCollection ms = regx.Matches(body);

                        foreach (Match m in ms)
                        {
                            string tmpLink = m.Value.ToString();

                        }
```

Now i want to further match if it contains a number after www. so i will mark it as spam.Or there can be one complete code insteads of this inner loop .Same goes with email get those emails which have number after @.

Comment: Nothing ensures a *www.* here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex works like this:
http://([\w+?\.\w+])+([a-zA-Z0-9\~\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)_\-\=\+\\\/\?\.\:\;\'\,]*)?

`http://`  -  http://

`([\\w+?\\.\\w+])+`  -  any of the following occurring one or more times - word character,`+`,`?`,`.` (unwanted escaping for `.`)

`([a-zA-Z0-9\\~\\!\\@\\#\\$\\%\\^\\&amp;\\*\\(\\)_\\-\\=\\+\\\\\\/\\?\\.\\:\\;\\'\\,]*)?` - an optional part with word characters or the listed characters occurring zero or more times (full of unwanted escaping)

For `http://` to be followed by `www.` use `http://www\.` and `http://www\.\d+[\w.]*` matches `http://www.` followed by one or more digits followed by zero or more word characters or dots.

For emails with digits following `@`, use `[A-Za-z]\w+\@\d+[\w.]*`.

**Note:** I'm not sure about your requirement.

Comment: Basically i am checking for spam emails in outlook , so if in any email if there is a number after www. in url example : http://www.123bbc.com or in an email john@14534asd.com or john@23.com
of in url www.1234345.com its spam.

Comment: @confusedMind first regex matches `http://www.123xyz.qqq` and not `http://www.xyz.qqq`. Second one matches `john@14534asd.com` and not `john@asd.com`

Comment: Thank you will test it and let you know :)